# Python traceback issues

Tags: python

So I've been learning the basics of Python and threw this bit of code together but i'm having a few issues. So I basically want it to check if the user input matches a value in the 'con' variable and if it matches to print correct, if it's wrong print not recognised.

```
    #countries.py
con = [ "uk" , "japan" , "us" ]

uInput = input("Enter the country: ")
if uInput == con:
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Not Recognised")
```

Also, I'd like to add `lower()` to the users input, so the capitalisation doesn't affect the results but don't really know where to add it.

Like I say, I'm new to coding so go easy!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`con` is a list and `uInput` is a string.  Meaning, they will never be equal.

Instead, you want to use [`in`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) here:

```
if uInput in con:
```

The above code will test if the value of `uInput` can be found in `con`.

---

Then, you can add [`str.lower`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) for case-insensitive searching:

```
if uInput.lower() in con:
```

This code will test if a lowercase version of the value of `uInput` can be found in `con`.

Comment: Ok, so I have done that but it spits out this error in the terminal:   
Enter the country:  uk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'uk' is not defined

Comment: @user3407221 - You must be using Python 2.x.  Use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) to get the user input instead of [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).  The former will return a string object where as the latter will try to evaluate its input.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain that method straight onto the string that `input()` returns:

```
uInput = input("Enter the country: ").lower()
```

Note also that the input will never be `== con`, as `con` is a list and the input is a string; instead, try:

```
if uInput in con:
```